# AVL Trees in C with validation

Tags: c, data-structures

```
struct node *deleteAvl(struct node *curr, int key)
{
    if (curr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Data not found\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (key < curr->key)
    {
        curr->left = deleteAvl(curr->left, key);
    }
    else if (key > curr->key)
    {
        curr->right = deleteAvl(curr->right, key);
    }
    else
    {
        if (curr->left == NULL || curr->right == NULL)
        {
            struct node *temp = curr->left != NULL ? curr->left : curr->right;
            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                printf("Data Found\n");
                printf("Value %d was deleted\n", key);
                free(curr);
                curr = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                *curr = *temp;
                printf("Data Found\n");
                printf("Value %d was deleted\n", temp->key);
                free(temp);
            }
            if (curr == NULL)
            {
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            struct node *temp = leftRightChild(curr->left);
            curr->key = temp->key;
            curr->left = deleteAvl(curr->left, temp->key);
        }
    }
    curr->heigt = 1 + max(getHeight(curr->left), getHeight(curr->right));
    int balance = getBalance(curr);
    if (balance > 1)
    {
        if (getBalance(curr->left) >= 0)
        {
            return rightRotate(curr);
        }
        else if (getBalance(curr->left) < 0)
        {
            curr->left = leftRotate(curr->left);
            return rightRotate(curr);
        }
    }
    else if (balance < -1)
    {
        if (getBalance(curr->right) <= 0)
        {
            return leftRotate(curr);
        }
        else if (getBalance(curr->right) > 0)
        {
            curr->right = rightRotate(curr->right);
            return leftRotate(curr);
        }
    }
    return curr;
}
```

> if i input the values: 6, 27, 19, 11, 36, 14, 81, 63, 75
> and I deleted the values: 14, 75, 36, 19, 11. Why when I delete the number 75, the validation is 63, but 14,75,36,19,11 the number is deleted. how do you get the validation out in accordance with the numbers 14,75,36,19,11.

printf ("Data Found \ n");

printf ("Value% d was deleted \ n", temp-> key);

**Data Found
Value 63 was deleted**

Comment: Please don't tag C questions with the C++ tag.

Comment: This code is in C language

Comment: But the question was tagged with C++. Why?

Comment: Sorry, my question is only C tagged, there is no c ++ tag

Comment: @HanIzza, the edition history will tell you... the original post was issued with the `c++` tag, so don't deny the evidence, please.